# OData multiple DTO for same entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, wcf-data-services

In my ODATA web api v4, I am trying to allow multiple DTO for single entity.

```
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
var version = builder.MaxDataServiceVersion;
builder.EntitySet<PersonModelAdminDTO>("PersonModel").EntityType.HasKey(p => p.RecordId);
builder.EntitySet<PersonModelBasicDTO>("PersonModel").EntityType.HasKey(p => p.RecordId);
```

I have tried the above code but it says entity is already added.

Basically since I do not want to expose all properties of PersonModel to Basic user I have created seperate DTO.

I do not want to show both PersonModelAdminDTO and PersonModelBasicDTO sets separately to the client metadata because that will make it confusing.

--- Edited ----

Further to the suggestion I have tried
https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApi/v4/DynamicEdmModelCreation

modified it slightly

```
await SendQuery("/odata/mydatasource/Products?$select=ID", "Query the Products entity set.");
```

There seems to be existing bug open:

stackoverflow.com/questions/29308157/

github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/175

Answer (score 0):

You can only really add one of these things to the metadata so I think that you have two options here:

1. You can add the full object and depending on the user, only populate the properties that they have access to. This is probably the easiest thing to do but it does mean that the properties will be in the metadata
2. You can create the model on every request and check which type of user it is to determine which DTO you add. There is an example of dynamic model building  [here](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApi/v4/DynamicEdmModelCreation) but it isn't centred around permissions

Comment: The second option does not support odata queries, ie $filter, $select etc

Comment: @mehwish It can do, this is how I have my system setup and it supports $filter and $select. Why do you think that it won't support that?

Comment: I have edited my question with your suggestion. Please let me know if you have a work around this issue.